# Can we integrate multiple module in spring boot?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot

Currently we use single module in spring boot , now we required a multiple modules in spring boot , does any one tell me about the how to integrate the multiple module in spring boot .

Comment: dunno what you mean

Comment: i want to integrate multiple modules in spring boot

Answer (score 0):

Yes to achieve you need to tell your SpringBootApplicationClass to look for controllers in your module because your sub modules will not be scanned in that class.You can use @ComponentScan("package path") to tell main class to scan for the package that contains your modules.

Comment: you can look for it on web